# Docker --env-file - executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, debian, environment-variables

I want to run my docker container with environment variables with the `--env-file` option, like mentioned in the docker doc: [docker run command](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/commandline/run/)

I've tried creating a file named `env.list` in my home dir `/home/jw/data` with the following content:

```
SSL_CERTIFICATE_PATH=/opt/onlyoffice/Data/certs/onlyoffice.crt
SSL_KEY_PATH=/opt/onlyoffice/Data/certs/onlyoffice.key
SSL_DHPARAM_PATH=/opt/onlyoffice/Data/certs/dhparam.pem
```

After that I added the directory `/home/jw/data/` to my `$PATH` environment variable:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/jw/data/; export PATH
```

On the same shell I started the docker container like this:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -d --name onlyoffice-document-server onlyoffice/documentserver --env-file /home/jw/data/env.list debian env
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 45ff897e0cfdc676f4f0bac98e027e2c567558a173a7f80c02ba6dc86482a176: [8] System error: exec: "--env-file": executable file not found in $PAT
```

I've also tried setting the `$PATH` under `root` and execute the mentioned run command, with the same error message.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`onlyoffice/documentserver` is at the wrong position.

Assuming that is the name of the container you want to start, it would have to be before `env` instead of `debian`, which is another image.

Answer (score 6):

I think flag placement matters,

```
docker run --network="host" --env-file .env container_id
```